# Program prints the wrong output

Tags: c, ascii

This program should print "SNP" but it prints "SNW".

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() { 
    int o = '!?zx' 
            ^ '!h4+'; 
    printf("%s\n", &o); 
    return (o ^ o); 
}
```

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Comment: Can you explain why you expect it to print "SNP"?

Comment: Putting any undefined- or endianness-related behaviour aside, the 3rd character of your output will have the value of `?` XOR `h`, which is `63^104` or `0x3F ^ 0x68`, or, in binary, `00111111 ^ 01101000`, This is (in binary) `01010111`, or `0x57`, or (decimal) 87 ... which is ASCII code for the `W` character. So, where lies your confusion?

Comment: There is a problem with three bits; see my answer below.

Comment: You should be aware that this program makes use of several instances of unspecified or implementation-defined behavior.  It's not required for a compiler to support multi-character character constants like `'!?zx'` at all, and if a compiler does, it's not guaranteed what order the characters will be in.  Printing a multi-character character using `%s` is a terrible idea, and is not guaranteed to work, as it, too, depends on implementation-defined byte order issues.  All in all this is a no-good, very bad, messed-up exercise you've been given, as it will teach you nothing but bad habits.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your program and got `SNW`.

As `^` is the **XOR** operation, I made it by hand and got the same result:

```
        Here is the problem
                |||
                VVV
 00100001 00111 111  01111010 01111 00   <- !?zx
 00100001 01101 000  00110100 00101011   <- !h4+
--------------------------------------- XOR
 00000000 01010 111  01001110 01011111   <- binary result
       00        57        4E       53   <- hexadecimal result
                  W         N        S   <- characters
```

Are you sure it would output `SNP` normally? The XOR operator between `?` and `h` gives `00111111^01101000` which is `01010111`, or `W` in Unicode or ASCII. `P` is `01010000`.

So I marked the problematic bits above and put them below.
The issue is that, it gives

```
the bits   111
before |   000
       V  ----- XOR
    01010  111
```

and 01010**111** makes W, instead of 01010**000** which would make P.

Also, due to endianness, you can get `WNS` as well as `SNW`.

Comment: In a big-endian machine the result would be `"\x00WNS"` and printing that would print nothing :-)